# Typescript: variable is assigned a value but never used, except it is used

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting the Typescript warning: `'isAuthenticated' is assigned a value but never used` for the component below
[image]

However, I am using `isAuthenticated` in my component as seen below.

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react'

const Profile: React.FC = () => {
    const { user, isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth0()

    if (isLoading) {
        return <div>Loading ...</div>
    }

    return (
        <>
            isAuthenticated && (
            <div>
                <img src={user?.picture} alt={user?.name} />
                <h2>{user?.name}</h2>
                <p>{user?.email}</p>
            </div>
            )
        </>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

Why am I receiving this warning when I've used the variable?

Comment: If you render it, you'll see "isAuthenticated &&" as literal output.  You want `{isAuthenticated && (`... and add a closing `}` at the end.

Comment: Oh man.... Thank you.. I'm new to react

Comment: No problem.  The `{` breaks out of literal mode into code mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used `Logical && Operator` wrong.
replace `()` with `{}`

more info : https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer is merely one implementation of what has been shared in the 'Comments' above by [user2740650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2740650/user2740650).

Credit where credit is due.

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react'

const Profile: React.FC = () => {
    const { user, isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth0()

    if (isLoading) {
        return <div>Loading ...</div>
    }

    return (
        <React.fragment>
            {isAuthenticated && (
                <div>
                    <img src={user?.picture} alt={user?.name} />
                    <h2>{user?.name}</h2>
                    <p>{user?.email}</p>
                </div>
            )}
        </React.fragment>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

My hope is that this, above answer, may be helpful to some future jsN00b.